# A table with two keys in Firebase

Tags: database, firebase

I have a Firebase database for recording grades of students to exercises. There is a "students" object that holds all student details, and an "exercises" object that holds all exercise details. Now the question is where to put the grade that a certain student scores in a certain exercise?

When a student enters the system, it needs to show the grades of this student to all exercises, so it makes sense to put all grades in the "student" object.

When a lecturer enters the system, it needs to show the grades of all students to a particular exercise, so it makes sense to put all grades in the "exercise" object.

So far, I put the grades in both places, but it lead to bugs, and apparently it is a design bug since the data is duplicated.

In an SQL database, I would just create a separate table called "grades", and have both "student_id" and "exercise_id" as keys in that table. This way it is easy to find all grades either by student_id or by exercise_id.

How can I do this in Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

think i would add all studentIds and excerciseIds into a grades collection, and just have all their grades their, and probaly duplicate extra the data needed from student collection + excercise as you suggest similar to sql approach.

if not that i would probaly checkout support for subcollectin queries as i belive its on the way? that way each excercise could have the student information as subcollection, either way duplicate the data and think like sql views.